# I can't get EditText to work in a class that isn't an activity

Tags: android, android-edittext, findviewbyid

I can't get `EditText` to work in a class that isn't an activity. I'm getting the stack trace error:

```
02-29 10:07:00.742: E/AndroidRuntime(1108): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-29 10:07:00.742: E/AndroidRuntime(1108): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
02-29 10:07:00.742: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2683)
02-29 10:07:00.742: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3110)
02-29 10:07:00.742: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:11934)
02-29 10:07:00.742: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
02-29 10:07:00.742: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-29 10:07:00.742: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
02-29 10:07:00.742: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
02-29 10:07:00.742: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-29 10:07:00.742: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
02-29 10:07:00.742: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
02-29 10:07:00.742: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
02-29 10:07:00.742: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-29 10:07:00.742: E/AndroidRuntime(1108): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
02-29 10:07:00.742: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-29 10:07:00.742: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
02-29 10:07:00.742: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2678)
02-29 10:07:00.742: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     ... 11 more
02-29 10:07:00.742: E/AndroidRuntime(1108): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-29 10:07:00.742: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at com.lifeApp.RegisterProcessing.createUser(RegisterProcessing.java:57)
02-29 10:07:00.742: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at com.lifeApp.RegisterActivity.onClick(RegisterActivity.java:69)
02-29 10:07:00.742: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     ... 14 more
```

---

My code is:
I have block quoted the error line

```
public void createUser(View v) {

            Date cal=Calendar.getInstance().getTime();

            EditText firstname = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.firstname);
            EditText lastname = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.lastname);
            EditText email = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.email);
            EditText phone = (EditText)  v.findViewById(R.id.phone);
            EditText address = (EditText)  v.findViewById(R.id.address);
            EditText password = (EditText)  v.findViewById(R.id.password);
            EditText confPassword = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.confPassword);


            //need to error check!!

            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
```

> ```
>           Log.i("firstname", ""+firstname.getText().toString());
> ```

```
            values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_FIRSTNAME, firstname.getText().toString());
            values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_LASTNAME, lastname.getText().toString());
            values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_EMAIL, email.getText().toString());
            values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_PHONE, phone.getText().toString());
            values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ADDRESS, address.getText().toString());
            values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_PASSWORD, password.getText().toString());
            values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_DATE, cal.toLocaleString());

            long insertId = database.insert(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_REGISTER, null,
                    values);
            // To show how to query
            Cursor cursor = database.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_REGISTER,
                    registerColumns,  MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID + " = ?", new String[] {""+insertId},
                    null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            //return cursorToREgister(cursor,policyId);
        }
```

Comment: com.lifeApp.RegisterProcessing.createUser(RegisterProcessing.java:57) see line no.57 in RegisterProcessing.java Something is null...

Comment: Please point out line 57 of `RegisterProcessing.java`.

Comment: hi guys, sorry for missing that information out Log.i("firstname", ""+firstname.getText().toString());

Comment: Create an entity class `UserInfo` and fill the values from EditText in `RegisterActivity.onClick`. Now call `createUser(UserInfo user)` method.

Answer (score 0):

the stack trace shows that problem is with context you should pass your activity context to this class and use it for ui processes 
and for edit texts use getEditableText().toString() instead of getText().toString()

Comment: hi thanks for your reply, I am trying to use context with findViewById() however it isn't working. I've now made the amendments to the getEditableText(). Thanks

Comment: hey if it helped then why you have down voted it 
any way in your activity from where you are calling this class pass context of that activity and use that in this class

Comment: sorry my finger slipped :) I have changed the findViewById() to EditText firstname = (EditText) ((Activity) context).findViewById(R.id.firstname); But I am getting the error 02-29 10:44:48.592: E/AndroidRuntime(1278): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to android.app.Activity

Comment: dont use context with findViewById() ithink problem is somewhere else please debug your code and then let me know in which line it get crashed